# Bulk Change format of Outlook 365 Contact Cards

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, office365

We recently had to recover a whole load of contact informations and contacts for a VIP on their local outlook.

However when this happened it changed the formatting of the business cards/contact cards.

Currently:

- **Person Name**
- Company Name

Wants/Was:

- **Company Name**
- Person Name

Ignore the bullet point just used this to help with formatting.

We know there is a way to do this manually but we can't find any solution to do this in bulk. The user has 100s of contacts and as such this would take hours/days to do.

Intermedia had no solutions and we can't find any online.

Any help greatly appreciated, currently in contact with MS to see if they have any solutions.

Comment: Two thoughts - although bear in mind I have no experience of Outlook 365: (1) Use the Outlook 365 API to scan and modify the contacts (2) Export the contacts to vcard and then write something in your language of choice to parse the file - it's a pretty simple format - and modify the contacts. Then import the revised vcards back into Outlook 365.

Comment: I'll have to see if there is some code I can steal as I'm afraid PS is not my strong suit. (yet)

Comment: If you can export a vcard for a problematic contact, adjust the details (to protect that persons privacy) and add it to your question (and the expected end result) then someone may be able to write something to do it for you - either in code or via something like Excel.

Comment: Can you provide sample screenshots of was/now? It's unclear what particular fields do you mean and in what place of the card.